# Declaring navigation & search box in css

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I want to declare navigation menu left side & search box in right side  in navigation menu  bar but my `css` code is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

**My Html Code :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>

            <div id= navigation>
                <ul>
                    <li> <ahref="index.html">Home</a><li>
                    <li><ahref="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>  
                <div id= from>
                    <form method = post action="" >
                        <input type="text" class= "form control" placeholder="Search">
                        <button class="button" type="Submit">"Submit"</button>  
                    </form>
        </body>
 </html>
```

**CSS code  :**

```
#body{#width:500px}
#navigation { 
    float:left;
    background: #1b1c1d;
    width: 960px;
}
#navigation ul { 
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-        weight: 200;  
}
#navigation ul li {
    display: inline; padding: 8px 12px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    color: #d5d4d4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li.active a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#from{
    width:280px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or Plunker link

Comment: Try wrapping your menu in a div (i.e, #menu) and wrapping your search in it's own div. Then deal with them as two separate item inside your navigation div. (i.e, you can float your #menu left, while floating your search right.) You'll have to display them as inline-block.

Comment: You might also want to put quotes around ID names ---- `<div id="navigation">`

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If yes, accept the answer by clicking the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` to `#navigation ul`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjygz/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in css and try is it ok

```
#navigation ul{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```